# java-Modify a search method to return a list of recipes that contain an ingredient

Tags: java, search

So I'm doing a project and one the cases asks for the user to input an ingredient and it'll print out all the recipes containing that ingredient.

The question says "Modify searchByIngredient to return a List variable instead of a single Recipe. The List will contain all recipes matching the search criteria."

My problem is that I can't get it to print all of the recipes that have the ingredient. It just prints the first one it finds.

This is the original code. It only prints out the first recipe it finds that contains the ingredient that the user is searching for.

```
  public Recipe searchByIngredient(String target) {
  for (Object ingred : mList) {
     Recipe i = (Recipe) ingred;
     if (i.hasIngredient(target)) {
        return i;
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This is the code that I tried to make, in order for it to print out all of the recipes that had the ingredient.

```
   public List searchByIngredient(String target) {
  for (Object ingred : mList) {
     Recipe i = (Recipe) ingred;
     if (i.hasIngredient(target)) {
        return (List) i;
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It would output:

```
Please enter an ingredient name:
avocado

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Recipe cannot be cast to List
at RecipeBook.searchByIngredient(RecipeBook.java:40)
at RecipeProgram.main(RecipeProgram.java:125)
Java Result: 1
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs is because you cast **Recipe** to **List** type.

```
 Recipe i = (Recipe) ingred;
 if (i.hasIngredient(target)) {
    return (List) i;
```

Actually, You can add the candidate Recipe to a List and return it when the for-loop is done.

Like,

```
public List searchByIngredient(String target) {
       List<Recipe> result = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
       for (Object ingred : mList) {
          Recipe i = (Recipe) ingred;
          if (i.hasIngredient(target)) {
            // return (List) i;
            //Add candidate Recipe into list
                      result.add(Recipe);
          }
       }
       //return null;
       return result;
     }
```